# Where can I download the Chileancredit data set that is part of smbinning in R

Tags: r

I have downloaded and installed the package smbinning in R
***library(smbinning).***
R has installed this package successfully. 
There is supposedly a data set called chileancredit that comes with the package
***data(chileancredit)*** yields nothing.

Where can I get hold of this data set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data()` you can see the datasets included in each package:

```
Data sets in package ‘smbinning’:

smbsimdf1                         Simulated Credit Data
smbsimdf2                         Monotonic Binning Sample Data
smbsimdf3                         Monotonic Binning Sample Data
```

"smbsimdf1" might be what you are looking for.

Comment: it's not included in the latest versions. you can see it in the older versions https://github.com/cran/smbinning/tree/6b29070c8e26557efc55c34a1b42f4131e8fd966/data

Comment: Thank you. I was able to download it.